# Multiple comparison in non-parametric data

Tags: multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

According to this: https://www.statisticshowto.com/multiple-testing-problem/ in non-parametric distributions I cannot perform FDR corrections. I have been searching for hours without finding anything similar on the internet. Could you please send me a link where I can see all the assumptions of FDR?

Thanks :)